# physical screen pixels with CSS

Tags: css, flash, zooming, resolution, pixel

I have a Flash object that I need to embed in a page, and I've got it in a wrapper div that is styled to the exact width of the object: 323px.  The problem I have is that when I zoom the whole page in the browser (for example, by using ctrl+mouse wheel, or ctrl++ or ctrl+-, the wrapper div zooms, while the flash object does not.  Is there a way that I can specify a width in physical screen pixels, so when I zoom in or out, the wrapper div stays the size of the Flash object?

Comment: I have never had this problem (Firefox) the flash objexts always resize, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You could use onResize in javascript, and always set the wrapper div's size to that fixed value of 323px

If you use jQuery see [this](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

> ```
> $(window).resize(function() {
>     $('#wrapper').width(323px);
> });
> ```

Hope this helps.